Ubuntu 20.04.6 system running in Oracle VM is unresponsive
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.6 in an Oracle VM on Windows 10, and after some updates of softwar on the Ubuntu system it is totally unresponsive.
What I mean it that when I start the VM I see the normal screen of ubuntu, with some favorite applications on the lest, the time and date on top , etc:

But there is no functionality - I can click with the mouse or type with the keyboard, but nothing is happening. The screen is like an image. I can click where I want, but nothing is happening.
I also did NOT change any settings.
How to recover this VM? Or should I reinstall a new VM? New Oracle? New Windows 10?
P.S. When I install a new Ubuntu instance that works again. I can click and open apps and use it (although the terminal does not work ...)

(although the terminal does not work ...) - Did you alter the default python version? That makes terminal (and a lot of other things) stop working

Yes seems that is the problem

Never ever change the default python version (that is like changing the vital organs of an animal and expecting it to still function smoothly - too many apps in Ubuntu directly depend on the default python). You can try to change the python version by opening a virtual terminal (ctrl + alt + f2 in the virtual keyboard of the VM) and running the command sudo update-alternatives --config python3 after logging in. If that does not work, you will have to reinstall Ubuntu.
